# missing "ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)" template in Visual studio 2015 update 3?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have Visual studio 2015 update 3. and I don't see the ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) template.

Do I need to switch to Visual Studio "15" Preview 4 ?
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs15-relnotes

Or will it get added to VS 2015 ? What am I missing?

Comment: Did you install the .NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2 ?

Comment: my bad - didn't read the instructions .

Comment: In my case, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40827063/1220550) helped as I didn't have `Microsoft Web Development Tools` installed.

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same problem...,

**Solution** that worked for me:

went to *Tools > Extensions and Updates > Updates*

if the problem is an outdated extension, you will see it under updates else you can search for it in the online tab or you can use this [Link](https://jacqueseloff.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/jacqueseloff/microsoftaspnetandwebtools-9689/14.1.21111.0/1482137806410/77371/12/DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe) 
which worked for me.

But I recommend that you use visual studio to get the current version.

*Make sure to close visual studio before performing the install.*

Updated Download Link
https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows

Answer (score 9):

You should install [.NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows)

Comment: working. I need to scroll down the page and option is available there. :)

Comment: doesn't VS 2015 support .net core 2.0 ?

Answer (score 9):

Solution that worked for me:

Go to Visual studio tools > Extensions and Updates > Updates -> Visual studio gallary

If you see Update for Microsoft.Net Core hit update and it should work.

[image]