# missing “ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)” template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to develop a ASP.NET Core application. I tried following the documentation (for example [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc)), but I fail to find the ASP.NET Core template. The dialog that should contain it looks like that instead: [image: the new project dialog].

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3, and installed the Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2 (I have also repaired and reinstalled it, without success).

Comment: Do you have the standard ASP.NET template? Have you also installed the Microsoft Web Developer Tools from the Visual Studio installer?

Comment: @ColinM I had some ASP.NET templates, but I didn't have the Web Developer Tools installed. It completely slipped my mind that this can be disabled in the installer. After rerunning the visual studio installer to install it, and reinstalling .NET Core, I now have the template. If you post this as an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: You should find it under the web tab

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ensure you have the `Microsoft Web Development Tools` installed which you can find in the Visual Studio installer under `Windows and Web Development`

Once installed, start up Visual Studio and check your templates again and you should see the ASP.NET Core templates.

**Update**

Per the comment below,

> For those who already had visual studio 2015+ installed but didn't add the feature during the inital installation, you have to download the main visual studio installer and modify its features

Comment: For those who already had visual studio 2015+ installed but didn't add the feature during the inital installation, you have to download the main visual studio installer and modify its features

Comment: @user1342086 thanks for the reminder, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Totally lost now. Tried everything and now I have a new web tab without core.

Comment: Have you installed the NET Core SDK?

Answer (score 2):

Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features >  Checked Use previews of the .NET Core SDK  and UnChecked Showw all .NET Core templates in the New project dialog... then restart visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

Fro those who have visual studio 2015 update 3 and selected Windows and Web Development while instaltion, but still can't find .net core. You can go to [Microsoft Targeting website](https://www.microsoft.com/net/targeting) download it seprately and install it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem. I installed [Install .NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=827546) and that works

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17264519)

Comment: @KurtVandenBranden The essential parts of the answer are "Install .NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2". If the link breaks, future viewers should be able to find a solution based on those keywords, right? The link is merely there for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Try change the framework version at the top.

If doesn't work, reinstall core and update 3 and watch if any message error shows up.

Comment: I tried all Framework versions, the only difference is that I get nothing at all before .NET Framework 4.5 (as expected). What I didn't expect is that I have no .NET Core Frameworks in the dropdown, only regular .NET Framework. Is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

Install  .NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2

Comment: Your answer does not help. Read op's question. "I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3, and installed the Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2 (I have also repaired and reinstalled it, without success)."

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Microsoft Web Development Tools first (Open Visual Studio installer, choose modify, tick Microsoft Web Development Tools, then update)
Then install Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your ASP.NET and Web tools.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDDvE.jpg)

Comment: please put the answer and not just a link to an article or document.

Comment: "Try updating your ASP.NET and Web tools" - isn't it an answer?

Comment: The answer should include instructions and put in your response. This is in case the source material changes or the link has moved.