# Missing ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) different and missing templates

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I've tried really hard to solve this myself but I can't. :(...

[Trust me I checked here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824231/missing-asp-net-core-web-application-net-core-template)

I tried to modify my installation, but all that did was change the titles to make things even more confusing.

Have a look here.

What I [should](https://www.microsoft.com/net/images/screenshots/VS2015_FileNewProject.png) be looking at.

What I [am really](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UDEf.png) looking at.

As you can see there are differences. After reading the below answer in another thread...

"Ensure you have the Microsoft Web Development Tools installed which you can find in the Visual Studio installer under Windows and Web Development

Once installed, start up Visual Studio and check your templates again and you should see the ASP.NET Core templates.

For those who already had visual studio 2015+ installed but didn't add the feature during the inital installation, you have to download the main visual studio installer and modify its features"

Things only got stranger with the titles being changed from `Class Library (.NET Core)` to `NetCoreClassLibrary` and `NetCoreConsoleApp`.

I have also followed instructions [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015).

What happened in the lead up?

First, I got update 3. Then I got `Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2` and installed. After that I modified my install to make it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYsNt.png), but after that failed I went back to recheck `update 3` but machine said that it was still installed. Now I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did everything right! (amazing, considering I am terrible at reading)

Turns out you must use the REPAIR button on the `Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2` thing if you were to mess up as bad as I did at the start. One new unasked unanswered question now answered. You're welcome.

To make things more clear, here's what happened.

I installed `update 3`, `Tooling preview 2`, THEN got `Microsoft web development tools`. After that I had to repair `Tooling preview 2` and then it worked.

Comment: I should try this :) I had the same issues with refactoring some assemblies... And last week I installed a fresh new mvc template, I upgraded to the latest libraries.. And it's all messed up. So I guess it's the only way to do, if you do not want to recreate each project one by one