# command 'dotnet new mvc' in Terminal but don't have mvc template

Tags: asp.net, macos, visual-studio-code

I Install .NET Core 2.2 on macOS Mojave , then type command 'dotnet new' in Terminal but don't have mvc template. I don't know why.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg085.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide more information about the error you are getting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [missing “ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)” template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824231/missing-asp-net-core-web-application-net-core-template)